# Is there a "Back Button" in Python PyS60

Tags: python, pys60

What it is I am creating an application on a Nokia mobile phone 5800 series and I was wondering if there was a back button function.

It would be better to give an example of what I mean,

If I typing in some onformation in this application and clicked next, but I forgot to add a small piece of information on the previous page. So is there a "Back button" function so I can go to the previous page in PyS60.

Could you give an example working code please, that would be greatful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
appuifw.app.menu = [(u"forward", forward), (u"back", back)]
```